# Get source of event in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have a list of `string` with which I want to create a menu of `ToolStripItem` (neither the list size nor its content is know at debug) and I want each item to execute the same event, so I go through the list with that code:

```
foreach (string i in items)
{
    ToolStripItem item = (ToolStripItem)toolStripMenuItem1.DropDownItems.Add(i);
    item.Click += new EventHandler(item_Click);
}
```

the problem is that in the `item_Click` method I need to know which of the above items triggered the event. If I were in WPF, I would have used `RoutedEventArgs` and its `.Source` proprety but since I am only in a regular Windows Forms app, I'm not quite sure how to do it. Is there a simple way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sender` parameter in your click event

```
var item = sender as ToolStripItem;
if(item != null)
{
    ...
}
```